# Error: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched. This is likely a bug in Gatsby and if refreshing the page does not fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

This error appears when I try to load an image using gatsby-image inside my gatsby project using static query. To give you some context, I made a monorepo with multiple gatsby websites altogether and reusing shared components. The hierarchy of folders is:

- packages

  - shared-ui

    - images

      - lightlogo.png
    - components

      - lightlogo.js
    - index.js
  - ventures

    - src

      - pages

        - 404.js

The index.js file exports the lightlogo component for the page to access it.

The code of the index.js is as follow:

```
export { default as LightLogo } from "./components/lightlogo"
```

And the code of the component is:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const LightLogo = ({ style }) => {
  const { data } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
        lightlogo: file(relativePath: { eq: "light_logo.png" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 78) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)
  return <Img style={style}
    fluid={data.lightlogo.childImageSharp.fluid} alt="Light HAG Logo"
  />
}

export default LightLogo
```

The code of the 404 page is:

```
import React from "react"
import { LightLogo } from "../../../shared-ui"

const NotFoundPage = () => (
  <div>
    <LightLogo />
    <h1>NOT FOUND</h1>
    <p>You just hit a route that doesn&#39;t exist... the sadness.</p>
  </div>
)

export default NotFoundPage
```

The gatsby config in the ventures folder is as follow:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `images`,
                path: `../shared-ui/images`,
            },
        },
        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
        `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
            options: {
                useMozJpeg: false,
                stripMetadata: true,
                defaultQuality: 75,
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
            options: {
                name: `HAG Ventures`,
                short_name: `HAG`,
                start_url: `/`,
                background_color: `#663399`,
                theme_color: `#663399`,
                display: `minimal-ui`,
                icon: `../shared-ui/images/light_logo.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
            },
        },
        // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
        // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
        // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    ],
}
```

My package.json is:

```
{
    "name": "@lerna-monorepo/ventures",
    "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
    "dependencies": {
        "@lerna-monorepo/shared-ui": "^1.0.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "framer-motion": "^1.8.4",
        "gatsby": "2.23.3",
        "gatsby-background-image": "^0.10.2",
        "gatsby-cli": "^2.14.1",
        "gatsby-image": "^2.2.38",
        "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.31",
        "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.27",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.21",
        "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.5.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.2.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.3.5",
        "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.26",
        "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.2.1",
        "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.2.2",
        "gatsby-source-rss-feed": "^1.2.2",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.7",
        "gsap": "^3.5.1",
        "lottie-player": "^1.0.0",
        "lottie-react": "^2.1.0",
        "lottie-web": "^5.7.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
        "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
        "react-lazyload": "^3.1.0",
        "react-slick": "^0.27.10",
        "react-waypoint": "^9.0.3",
        "scrollmagic": "^2.0.7",
        "scrollmagic-plugin-gsap": "^1.0.4",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
        "uninstall": "0.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "^1.19.1"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "gatsby"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "gatsby build",
        "develop": "gatsby develop",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
        "start": "npm run develop",
        "serve": "gatsby serve",
        "clean": "gatsby clean",
        "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
    }
}
```

I tried to reinstall all packages using yarn and it didn't work. When I query the image in the GraphiQl, the query successfully fetches the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the root of your Gatsby application is `packages/ventures` then Gatsby will not extract GraphQL queries from `packages/shared-ui`, even if you import them. This is because Gatsby uses static analysis to extract GraphQL queries before the code is parsed and evaluated, replacing the query with an identifier that refers to the resulting data for the query.

The way you would typically do something like this is as a [Gatsby Theme](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/themes/), which provide a mechanism for sharing code that gets treated largely like local components with some additional hooks and replacement capabilities.

Alternately, you might have some luck using the [Node APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/) to hook into the build process and copy files around (e.g. parsing the query out of the shared-ui component and rewriting it into the `ventures` folder `onPreBootstrap`), but it's going to be an uphill battle.